# Spring hibernate liquibase integration test fails

Tags: hibernate, spring-boot, liquibase

I can properly run my application with liquibase. The environment wer are using includes, spring, hibernate and mysql. When I try to run the integration test (which has h2 db), I get this exception:

```
 Caused by: liquibase.exception.DatabaseException: org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLException: Schema "pbr_tenant" not found; SQL statement: Caused by: liquibase.exception.DatabaseException: org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLException: Schema "pbr_tenant" not found; SQL statement: SET SCHEMA pbr_tenant [90079-197]
            at liquibase.integration.spring.SpringLiquibase.afterPropertiesSet(SpringLiquibase.java:307)
            at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.liquibase.LiquibaseAutoConfiguration$DataSourceClosingSpringLiquibase.afterPropertiesSet(LiquibaseAutoConfiguration.java:218)
            at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1803)
            at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1740)
            ... 105 more Caused by: org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLException: Schema "pbr_tenant" not found; SQL statement: SET SCHEMA pbr_tenant [90079-197]
```

Here’s how my application.yml for integration test looks like.

```
datasource:
  url: jdbc:h2:mem:data_import-int;DB_CLOSE_DELAY=-1;DB_CLOSE_ON_EXIT=FALSE;MODE=MySQL
  platform: h2
  username: sa
  password:
  driverClassName: org.h2.Driver
jpa:
  database-platform: org.hibernate.dialect.H2Dialect
  properties:
    hibernate:
      show_sql: true
      use_sql_comments: true
      format_sql: true


 liquibase:
      url: jdbc:h2:mem:pbr_tenant;MODE=Mysql;DB_CLOSE_DELAY=-1;DB_CLOSE_ON_EXIT=FALSE;DATABASE_TO_UPPER=false;INIT=CREATE SCHEMA IF NOT EXISTS pbr_tenant;SCHEMA=pbr_tenant
      contexts: integration-test
      parameters:
        schema: pbr-tenant
      change-log: classpath:db/changelog/fini-changelog.yml
```

What would be the work around.

Answer (score 1):

So you seem to be missing the schema. try the following.

```
datasource:
  url: jdbc:h2:mem:data_import-int;DB_CLOSE_DELAY=-1;DB_CLOSE_ON_EXIT=FALSE;INIT=CREATE SCHEMA IF NOT EXISTS pbr_tenant;MODE=MySQL
  platform: h2
  username: sa
  password:
  driverClassName: org.h2.Driver
```

to be able to create the schema if it does not exist.
You can also try:

```
datasource:
  url: jdbc:h2:mem:data_import-int;DB_CLOSE_DELAY=-1;DB_CLOSE_ON_EXIT=FALSE;INIT=CREATE SCHEMA IF NOT EXISTS pbr_tenant;SET SCHEMA pbr_tenant;MODE=MySQL
  platform: h2
  username: sa
  password:
  driverClassName: org.h2.Driver
```

To additionally select that schema